# iis asking for login credential when I add a second web site on my VM

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

In IIS, my default web site is configured with bindings:

```
  IP address: all unassigned
  Port: 80
  Hostname: <empty>
```

I add an asp.net web form application, configure windows authentication only, and everything works fine, User.IsAuthenticated = true

However If I try to add a second web site in IIS, the bindings need to be as follow, otherwise a login window will popup in any browser:

```
  IP address: all unassigned
  Port: 81 (port 80 is already assigned to "default site")
  Hostname: <empty>
```

If the enter a hostname (after having added it in the HOST file, with the same IP adress as my computer), then the login window will popup.

I would like some information as to why this is happening. I am maintaining old legacy code containing IIS mapping in the .csproj file, whith maps to a "real" host instead of just "localhost".

For example:

```
<IISUrl>http://<my-host>/<my-iss-application></IISUrl>
```

Does not seems to be best practice. The solution does not open unless  you go to IIS and create manually this site , and add it to the /etc/HOST file (windows 2019)

Thanks

Here`s my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you also use windows authentication for your second website (whether other authentication is disabled)? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I use windows authentication only, and yes all browser react the same. Its a "normalized" VM and how knows what the admin has configured...Could there be a security rule regarding windows authentication working only for localhost, and if you add another site along in IIS then its not working ? I'm doing dev so its just for comprehension.

Comment: Just find out I have the same login prompt if I use http://11.22.33.44/default.html, instead of http://localhost/default.html. Only windows authent is configured. I deleted all other web sites, its a fresh brand new IIS.

Comment: Can you share the configuration information of your website? For example web.config file.